# No puedo poner imagen de fondo en pagina web

Tags: css, background

No entiendo por que no me deja establecer ninguna imagen de fondo, pero cuando le doy la propiedad background-color si cambia.

css:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image: url(http://localhost/web/img/fondo.jpg) !important;
}
´´´
```

Comment: ¿La imagen que intentas cargar existe en esa ruta?

Comment: no hay que poner el valor de la url entre comillas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al cambiar en xampp el puerto del 80 al 8080 no me lo cogia por defecto en la ruta, no sabia que la tenia que poner.

localhost:PuertoEscucha

Answer (score 0):

¿Conoces la ruta relativa y la ruta absoluta?, normalmente el problema que tiene es que al usar la ruta como la tienes, depende de los cambios que hagas y del "contenedor" por asi decirlo, lo que debes hacer es una ruta similar a: `background-image: url(../web/img/fondo.jpg) !important;` donde los dos puntos del comienzo hace que la ruta tome en cuenta donde esta el css y dese hay buscar la nueva ruta, si no me entiende, de nuevo busca ruta relativa o ruta absoluta